# Grails: Forget objects in IntegrationSpec setup

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm, integration-testing, spock

So I am working with Grails.  My application involves an object coming in, and being updated in the db and returned.  It's this behavior I am trying to test in a Spock IntegrationSpec.

Essentially, my test looks like this (pseudo-code)

```
setUp
{
  Session sess = sessionFactory.openSession();
  Transaction tx = null;
  try{
  ...
  //These loaded fixtures include the shop
  //that I want to update
  fixtures = fixtureLoader.load(fixtureLocationsArray)
  ...
  tx.commit()
  ...
  sessionFactory.currentSession.flush()
  sessionFactory.currentSession.clear()
}

void testUpdate()
{
    Shop shop = fixtures.shop
    shop.discard()

    //Pure, unadulterated desperation below
    sessionFactory.currentSession.flush()
    sessionFactory.currentSession.clear()
    sessionFactory.getCache().evictEntityRegion(Shop)

    ShopDTO shopDto = convertToDTO(shop)
    shopDto.name = "Updated Shop"     

    //Chokes while in the controller
    returnedShopDTO = dtoController.update(shopDto)
}
```

I have tried everything, including wrapping my fixture creation in a transaction, evicting, discarding and doing whatever I can to make the session "forget" the object.  No matter what I do, I always get an error like

```
org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException: 
Row was updated or deleted by another transaction 
(or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect)
```

or it will complain that something with that id already exists in the session.  From what I can tell, the entire test occurs in one fat daddy session.  So when I go to "update" it inserts the fixture, and then calls "select last_row_id" or something.  It then assigns the next id to my updated shop.  So in the end, I get two inserts if it doesn't crash, the first from the fixture, the second from my save/merge call.

Any help on creating fixtures, and then making them disappear from the session/transaction/doo-hickey is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's not clear to me *when* do you want the fixture disappear from db. As I can remember grails integration features run inside a transaction by default (see [docs] (http://www.grails.org/doc/2.3.7/guide/single.html#integrationTesting)), so they should get wiped at the end of each feature.

Comment: If you want to use fixtures as a "template" for your shopDTO and get them deleted from db before conversion, instead, I would go with another pattern, but I find it difficult to say from your example.

Comment: @ManuelVio Basically I wanted the fixture to remain in the database, but not be present in the session.  So the fixture would have to disappear from the session after the setUp function.  I'm not sure if setUp occurs in the same transaction as the prospective test.

Comment: I see. I strongly believe that `setUp` method will run in the same transaction as the feature, but the `discard()` call alone should detach the instance from the session skipping any automatic save at session close. Is `shop` instance being manipulated in `convertToDTO` call?

Comment: @ManuelVio No, the shop object isn't being manipulated.  But what is happening is that I am essentially copying that information to another shop instance through the DTO.  The end result is that at the end, the session manager sees 2 objects with the same id, neither of which have been persisted.  It's not a problem anymore though, I've switched to PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had to disable versioning on my project.  I did this by adding the following code to my domain class.  I'm not sure if this is the correct solution, but it made the various errors go away.

```
static mapping = {
    ...
    version false
    ...
}
```